# @NonNull Annotation not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public
@NonNull
Result handleFollowForwardResult(@NonNull Result tempResult, @NonNull Result oldResult) {
    return null;
}
```

does not give any errors or warning? Isn't the point of the annotation to check for exactly this?

Answer (score 8):

This works in my copy of Android Studio 0.8.11. Try the following:

- If you're running an old version of Android Studio, update.
- Make sure your **Inspections** > **Constant conditions & exceptions** inspection is enabled.
- In **Inspections** > **Configure annotations**, make sure your **Nullable annotations** list includes `android.support.annotation.Nullable`, and your **NotNull annotations** list includes `android.support.annotation.NonNull`.